# Ensuring result order when joining, without using an order_by

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a mysql plugin that will return a result set in a specified order. Part of the result set includes a foreign key, and I'd like join on that key, while ensuring the order remains the same.

If I do something like:

```
    select f.id, 
           f.title 
      from sphinx s 
inner join foo f on s.id = f.id 
     where query='test;filter=type,2;sort=attr_asc:stitle';
```

It looks like I'm getting my results back in the order that sphinx returns them. Is this a quirk of mysql, or am I assured that a join won't change the order?

Comment: If you do **not** provide an `ORDER BY` in your query(s), the order will be the order as originally inserted.

Comment: Its intriguing to me that most of the answers here seem to have misunderstood a key part of the question.  His plugin guarantees ordering without the join (and w/o an order by) on MySQL.  He's asking whether a join on MySQL will affect that.  Its not a question about the sql standard (which doesn't guarantee this), but of the specific implementation in MySQL.  I wonder if a better answer would be available on Serverfault?

Comment: Jsight nailed this - the key part of this question is that the results from the select are GUARANTEED to be in the correct order, thanks to the plugin. Will using a join change that order? My initial tests show that it won't but I'm not yet ready to base my decision on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you need a guaranteed order in the results of a query, use ORDER BY. Anything else is wishful thinking.**

To give some insight on this, many databases divide execution steps in a way that can vary depending on the execution plan of the query, the amount of available CPU, and the kinds of optimizations the database can infer are safe. If a query is run in parallel on multiple threads the results can vary. If the explain plan changes, the results can vary. If multiple queries are running simultaneously, the  results can vary. If some data is cached in memory, the results can vary.

If you need to guarantee an order, use ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that sql guarantees which table drives the ultimate sort order.  Having said that, unless I would be very surprised if MySQL rewrites your query in such a way that the order changes.

Comment: The order of results from a query (that doesn't specify an ORDER BY) can vary for many subtle and difficult to anticipate reasons.

Answer (score 1):

SQL makes no guarantees about the result set order of a SELECT, which includes joins.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, SQL does not guarantee the order after such operation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific order guaranteed unless you specify an `ORDER BY` statement.
Since you mentioned that you were using a plugin that returns result sets in a specified order, I'm assuming that that plugin generates SQL that will add the ORDER BY statement.
If you do joins, one thing to look out for is the column names of the tables you're joining on. If they're named the same, your query might brake or order by a different column than intended.

Comment: It does not generate any sql - it communicates with an outside daemon.